# WebRTC + Web App: Remote video muted after connection establishment

Tags: javascript, web, video, webrtc, mute

I'm currently troubleshooting an issue related to streaming live video.

The symptoms I'm seeing appears to be related to this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/muted%7Csort:date/discuss-webrtc/x-qPgG4aONI/Hgss1q4GCQAJ

I've been able to reproduce the problem in two different ways.

The first scenario involves three different web browsers / computers, etc. I'll give these browsers the names Persons A, B, and C. Person A will be the host. Persons A and B are able to see each other. Persons B and C cannot.

The other scenario involves two different web browsers / computers, etc (we'll call them Person A & B). Again, one-to-one peer communication is successfully established, and both users are able to see each other. In this scenario, I had programmatically added some source code so that Person B can dynamically destroy then rebuild the video element (and, in turn, stopping and restarting the web camera). Person B destroying everything yields expected behavior. However, when Person B decides to restart the web camera, Person A is unable to see Person B.

I decided to create event handlers for both the MediaStreamTrack and the video element. In a perfect world, my logs would look like this:

```
tracks received from peer: (2) [MediaStreamTrack, MediaStreamTrack]
mute event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "audio", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: false, …}
mute event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "video", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: false, …}
end event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "audio", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: false, …}
loadstart event triggered...
onloadedmetadata event triggered...
canplay event triggered...
canplaythrough event triggered...
```

However, in the event that the receiving user is unable to view the video stream, the onloadedmetadata event is never triggered. Instead, the video media stream track ends up being muted:

```
tracks received from peer: (2) [MediaStreamTrack, MediaStreamTrack]
mute event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "audio", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: false, …}
mute event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "video", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: false, …}
loadstart event triggered...
mute event triggered for track: MediaStreamTrack {kind: "video", id: "...", label: "...", enabled: true, muted: true, …}
```

I would like to understand the variants that could contribute to this type of behavior, and any options that I may have in order to resolve this, if possible. I tried reading through the official WebRTC documentation; however, I really couldn't find any clues. Perhaps I didn't know where to look.

Thanks for your time and consideration.